# Could not invoke FORMAT function im MSSQL by using JPA criteria

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, criteria

I'm trying to execute this query by using JPA criteria:

I'm trying to execute this query by using JPA criteria:

```
SELECT format(data_creazione_pratica, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
FROM tcigdbexternal.ristoratori_svil.pratica
```

... So I wrote this JAVA code:

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();                  
final CriteriaQuery<String> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(String.class);            
final Root<Pratica> root = criteria.from(Pratica.class);                                     
criteria.select(criteriaBuilder.function("FORMAT", String.class, root.get("dataInserimento"),
        criteriaBuilder.literal("dd/MM/yyyy")));
```

... But I obtain this exception:

```
task-1|ERROR|requestId_6|i.p.r.m.a.w.r.c.PraticaController[PraticaController.java:50]|Exception occurred
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: 
    No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode    \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: 'function (FORMAT)'      
        +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'FORMAT' {originalText=FORMAT}      
            \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'         
                +-[DOT] DotNode: 
                    'pratica0_.data_creazione_pratica' 
                    {propertyName=dataInserimento,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=dataInserimento,path=generatedAlias0.dataInserimento,tableAlias=pratica0_,className=mypackage.Pratica,classAlias=generatedAlias0}
                    |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'pratica0_.id_pratica' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=it.poste.ristoratori.ministero.application.entity.Pratica, tableAlias=pratica0_} 
                    |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'dataInserimento' {originalText=dataInserimento}
            \-[QUOTED_STRING] LiteralNode: ''dd/MM/yyyy''
                    [select function('FORMAT', generatedAlias0.dataInserimento, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
                    from mypackage.Pratica as generatedAlias0];
                    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException:
                    No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode    
            \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: 'function (FORMAT)'
                +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'FORMAT' {originalText=FORMAT}
                    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
                    +-[DOT] DotNode: 'pratica0_.data_creazione_pratica' {propertyName=dataInserimento,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=dataInserimento,path=generatedAlias0.dataInserimento,tableAlias=pratica0_,className=mypackage.Pratica,classAlias=generatedAlias0}
                    |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'pratica0_.id_pratica'
                    {alias=generatedAlias0, className=mypackage.Pratica, tableAlias=pratica0_}
                    |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'dataInserimento' {originalText=dataInserimento}
                    \-[QUOTED_STRING] LiteralNode: ''dd/MM/yyyy''
                    [select function('FORMAT', generatedAlias0.dataInserimento, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
                    from mypackage.Pratica as generatedAlias0]
                    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
```

Comment: Personally, I recommend not using `FORMAT`, unless you're dealing with scalar values. `CONVERT` and a style code is far more performant; especially with large data sets. But why are you changing the date to a `varchar` anyway? Your presentation layer should be defining the **display** format, not SQL Server.

Comment: [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: I have tryed with this 
    `criteria.select(criteriaBuilder.function("CONVERT", String.class, root.get("dataInserimento"),
      criteriaBuilder.literal("103")));`
but with no success: could you write an example by using JPA Criteria?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me

Since Hibernate 5.2.18, you can use the MetadataBuilderContributor utility to customize the MetadataBuilder even if you are bootstrapping via JPA.

The `MetadataBuilderContributor` interface can be implemented like this:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
    implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
     
 @Override
 public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
        "group_concat",
        new StandardSQLFunction(
            "group_concat",
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING
        )
    );
 }
}
```

And, we can provide the SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor via the hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor configuration property:

```
<property>
    name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor"
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.query.function.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor"
</property>
```

Reference: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/